# How to clear animation data from a premade model?

Tags: animation, pose-mode

I have purchased a riggend and animated model off the internet ([link to model](https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/black-cattle-animated-3d-1907491)) and I want to clear the data animation on it and just create my own animatio. I have tried to clear the animation data on the object, but only the skeleton loses the animation and the mesh keeps running the animation (if does not follow the skeleton anymore).

Before clearing animation data:
[image]

After clearing animation data:
[image]

I have tried importing the object and its data into another blender project and I have been able to animate it this way, but there are some particles and details in the main project that I can't transfer, so this is why I'm looking for a way to modify the main blender file.

Comment: I'm not sure if this'll work, and I don't have time right now to set up some animation to try it out, hence a comment instead of an answer. Have you tried unparenting the mesh from the armature, then clear all animation data from both the model and the armature (do not delete any vertex groups), and finally reparent by using the option that's called _Armature Deform_ (i.e. no empty groups, no automatic weights, no envelope weights). The weights should have been retained from before you unparented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this:

- Switch to the Dope Sheet (Shortcut: <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>F12</kbd>  You may have to type it twice to get the Dope Sheet rather than the Timeline)
- Make sure that this group of icons on the right looks like this:

  [image: visibility settings]

  That is, from left to right,

  - disable "Only Show Selected"
  - enable "Show Hidden"
  - disable "Only Show Errors"
- Hover over the main window
- Select All (shortcut <kbd>A</kbd>)
- Type <kbd>X</kbd> to bring up the delete menu and select *Delete Keyframes*

  [image: Delete menu]
- To return to the 3D viewport use <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>F5</kbd>

That should remove all animations, unless you have some baked physics.

Comment: Thank you! The main problem was the baked physics that I managed to get rid of after unbaking it.